# Multiple Groupings within a Content Query Web Part

Tags: sharepoint

Does anyone know of a way to do multiple groupings on a content query web part. I have been able to customeize everything else, but the sub groupings issue has me.

What I need to do is, first group the list by column1, then within that grouping group on column2.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the `ContentQueryMain.xsl` you need to modify the `<xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.Body">` but that would end up having you to hardcode which group you want to add. The [Extended CQWP](http://www.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ProjectName=imtech&ReleaseId=12511) and the [Enhanced CQWP](http://www.codeplex.com/ECQWP) might give you more options (I could not find a feature list to confirm if you can do multiple groups)